# C - Thread Sync

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I have made this struct with a thread:

```
struct backup_t {
    int sockfd;
    int size;
    char *buffer;
    pthread_t server_thread;
};
```

This is the function thread executes:

```
void* backup_secundary_server(void *args) {
    struct backup_t *backup = (struct backup_t *) args; 
    if(send_message(backup->sockfd, backup->size, backup->buffer) == -1) {
            close(backup->sockfd);
            backup->sockfd = 0;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

 int send_message(int sockfd, int size, char* buffer) { 

    if(write(sockfd, &size, sizeof(int)) < 0){
           close(sockfd);
           return -1;       
    }
    if(write_all(sockfd, buffer, size) < 0){
           close(sockfd);
           return -1;       
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
 }
```

This where thread is created:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
             ...
    struct backup_t backup; 
    backup.sockfd = sockfdSecundaryServer;
    backup.size = sizeReceived;
    backup.buffer = receivedBuffer;

    if(pthread_create(&backup.server_thread, NULL, &backup_secundary_server, (void*)&backup)) {
            return -1;
    }
    pthread_join(backup.server_thread, NULL);

    if (send_message(pollfdSecundary[i].fd, sizeSend, sendBuffer) == -1)
            return -1;

            ...
}
```

I don't know why this is not working with this thread implementation. The program is in infinite loop.

Comment: Infinite loop or blocking? I don't see any loops at all.

Comment: side note: no need to cast a `void*` to any other type. This is C and not C++.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are there any error messages? Does the process stall?

Comment: From what we see, most probably `send_message()` blocks, either one or the other.

Comment: The problem is the message is not being sent. There are no error messages.

Comment: Do you open the socket somewhere?  Check your return codes.  It's one thing to know your calls are failing by checking for -1 but it is more helpful to know *why* by using `perror` and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The infinite loop may happen in write_all() which you should be implemented using the **while** or **for** loop. You probably not handling some error code there - check this. I would suggest you using **perror** function to check error codes returned from standard functions that you are calling.

```
stat = write(sockfd, buffer, size);
if (stat < 0) {
    perror("write");
    // handle error
    ...
}
```

You also have one design flaw: closing the same socket twice when **write()** or **write_all()** fails in **send_message()** that have small chance to lead to very tricky bug (socket descriptor can be reused by another thread and you will close it here inadvertently).